# What was the message Chewbacca told Rey he would deliver to Finn?

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi, rey, star-wars-finn, chewbacca

In The Last Jedi,

> Just before Rey gets into the Millennium Falcon's escape pod, she asks Chewie to give Finn a message.

However, their conversation slips into [Shyriiwook](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Shyriiwook) and (most of?) the audience couldn't understand what was said.

**What was Rey's message to give Finn?**

Comment: How would anyone know? Out of interest?

Comment: one of the best lines from force awakens is "you understand that thing? YES, and that THING understands you so watch what you say" - it's never really important that we know what he says. just that we "get it" kind of like how the characters in the movies do.

Comment: I think the message went something like RrRrRrRraaaaaaaAAAAAAAAAHHHHHHHH

Answer (score 12):

**No one knows.**

That was the entire point of the writing choices for that scene.

> Rey: "Tell him...." *(pauses to think, unsure)*
>
> Chewie: *(something no one in the audience can understand)*
>
> Rey: Yeah, perfect.  Tell him that.

If the writers had been able to think of a *really good* line to put there, maybe they would have.

Instead, they made it a subtle joke about the fact that all the other characters can understand Chewie even though no audience member can.

Comment: Not all the other characters can understand Chewie. In fact, probably only a few can -- Han and Rey for sure, but not Finn, for example. So I guess Chewie would have had to find someone to translate.

Comment: I'm moderately surprised because I would've thought one could translate Chewbacca's language like we can for Klignon and other developed fictional languages. No such luck?

Comment: @Hack-R sure, how about you start by transcribing it phonetically?

Answer (score 4):

There's nothing in either of the novelisations to indicate what was said. Under the circumstances, I think we can assume that whatever he said was heartfelt but doesn't translate well.

> *“If you see Finn before I do, tell him…” she began.
>
>   Chewbacca yowled.
>
>   “Yeah. Perfect. Tell him that.”*
>
> <sub><sup>[The Last Jedi: Official Novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Last_Jedi:_Expanded_Edition)</sup></sub>

and

> *The Wookiee yowled, disapproving of her plan. But she was grateful he didn’t try to stop her. He helped her get into the pod. “If you see Finn before I do, tell him…” She faltered, unable to find the words she wanted to say.
>
>   Chewbacca nodded and ruffed.
>
>   “Yeah, perfect. Tell him that.”*
>
> <sub><sup>[The Last Jedi: Junior Novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Last_Jedi:_A_Junior_Novel)</sup></sub>

Answer (score -4):

If there is a parallel between The Last Jedi and the Original Trilogy, it is obviously with The Empire Strikes Back. So Rey going to face Kylo and Stoke is a parallel with Luke rushing to Bespin to face Vader and save his friends. And Luke didn't leave a message for anyone then, so I feel your conclusion is based on a faulty premise. – scott Mar 21 at 15:21

The Last Jedi and The Return of the Jedi, and Empire Strikes Back have a lot of similarities. But Rian did his best to take scenes from the TRJ, and TESB and put it in TLJ. There is a parallel between Rey looking for something to say to Finn, that does parallel Luke speaking with Leia. The parallel is:

**Luke was speaking to Leia before going to face Darth Vader.**

1. Rey was speaking to Chewi to relay a message to Finn, before going to face Kylo Ren.
2. Luke has feelings and concern for Leia when he was speaking to her
   about what he is about to do.
3. Rey has feelings and concerns for Finn, when she is speaking about him,
4. In the Novel of TLJ Chewi was telling Rey not to go.
5. As Leia was telling Luke not to go, Luke was wearing all black when he was speaking to Leia.
6. Finn at this scene Rey was talking to Chewie he was wearing all black and look just like Luke Skywalker in the Return of the Jedi when he was with Vader.
7. Before Luke went to face Vader he was giving **advice from Yoda** and Obi Wan as a Force Ghost.
8. Just as Rey before she went to face Kylo she was given advice by Luke, then **Luke spoke with Yoda**.
9. When Luke was speaking with Leia he knew there was a chance he would not return.
10. When Rey was talking to Chewie about Finn she was choked up also so much so she did not know if she would return to see Finn, so she  left a message to Chewie if he saw Finn before her. Because there was a chance she would not make it back. This is the scene in the Return of the Jedi Luke was faced with the probability that he would not return so he told Leia if he did not return she is the last hope.

---

***This is my fan-fiction*** - Rey was telling Chewie and lost for words, Chewie took the words from her if she does not return *Finn is the last hope*.

Comment: Fan fiction isn’t considered an answer here. Answers here are supposed to be at least somewhat supported by canon.

Comment: The Last Jedi movie and novel is trash and have a lot of plot holes and conflictions in them, and with TFA. You not going find answer to what Chewi said unless you look at Rian Johnson did with the last Jedi and admit he is not a good writer so he took scenes and lines from the Empire Strikes back and Return of the Jedi and plug them in TLJ.  This scene with Chewie and Rey from the Return of the Jedi. Rey right before she left to seen Kylo is the same when Luke was going to see Vader, and told Leia who another lead if he do not return she the last hope. Finn is the second lead of TLJ.